# How do I convert from Cartesian to conical coordinates?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have some polygons I would like to map onto the face of a cone.

I can see from [this page](http://www.math.montana.edu/frankw/ccp/multiworld/multipleIVP/cylindrical/body.htm#skip3) that I can convert  the points of the polygon to cylindrical coordinates, which is almost what I want.

How do I go about modifying the formulas to work for conical coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you already have the formulas for converting from conical to rectangular coordinates as listed on the [Wikipedia page for conical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_coordinates). You'll need to solve for r, μ, and ν in terms of x, y, and z to get your answer. I can't see offhand the easiest way to find a general formula, but if you're trying to find it for particular values of r, μ, and ν, it shouldn't be too hard.